# Calling command prompt from Qt application without freezing?

Tags: c++, qt, command-line

In my Qt GUI application, I am calling the command prompt through:

```
system("lots.exe & of.exe && commands.exe");
```

It opens up the command prompt (like I want it to), but freezes the Qt GUI application until I close the command prompt.  Is there someway to prevent this? I saw that there is a QProcess class, but can't get it to bring up the command prompt.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does "&&" work? I would expect it to not work, as that should be syntax of the shell (cmd.exe, bash, etc.) and QProcess doesn't handle that. EDIT: stupid me, this is still system()...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`QProcess` is really the answer.  If you want to use something like `system()` you'll have to either put the call in another thread or use `popen` or something simmilar for your platforms.

`QProcess` does have the `setReadChannel` which you could use to display your own console window to show the output.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put that system call in a separate thread.

Comment: No need to do that when QProcess is available.  Also there would be no good way to interrupt the thread while it was blocked in system(), which could cause problems if the underlying .exe's don't exit for a long time (or ever)

Comment: Which is a general problem with system(), I agree :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need any of the output, the easiest way would be to use QProcess::startDetached().

http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qprocess.html#startDetached

If you do need the output, QtConcurrent::run with a futurewatcher containing the output would be less overhead/work than deriving QThread.