# do not show cmd window in qt project

Tags: qt, ffmpeg, cmd

I'm using ffmpeg command in Qt GUI application (for merging mp3 files into one file). And when I'm running my application the results of merging files showing in cmd window. How can I hide cmd window that users can not see it.

```
QString mergeMp3FilesStr = "ffmpeg -y -i \"concat:";
/*....some part of code*/
mergeMp3FilesStr+=" \" -c copy D:\\Mp3Files\\mergedMp3.mp3"
system((const char *)mergeMp3FilesStr.toStdString().c_str());


And so command is looking like this (I'm viewing result with QDebug):
ffmpeg -y -i "concat:D:\Mp3Files\a.mp3|D:\Mp3Files\a.mp3|D:\Mp3Files\a.mp3 " -c copy D:\Mp3Files\mergedMp3.mp3
```

Comment: Can you show more code on how you start the ffmpeg command?

Comment: Thanks for response.
I have already edited my question and added some part of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html) is the recommended way for external programs, so that you can have a better and finer control, and more portable. You may also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227767/how-to-run-a-system-command-in-qt), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260072/calling-command-prompt-from-qt-application-without-freezing) for some more information.

Comment: Thanks @YamnHon.CHAN, it helped.
I solved this with QProcess::execute function.